# matplotlib bar chart not showing up in container

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am working in python with pandas and matplotlib. I set up 4 containers to put my charts in, and for some reason, I can't get a chart to go in my 3rd container,`ax3`.

This line of code is what I am trying:

```
ax3.bar(range(len(bar_chart_data)), bar_chart_data['count'], color='r')
```

The line below actually makes a bar chart with my data appear:

```
bar_chart_data.plot.bar()
```

But I don't know how to make this one that works move into my container I have set up for it.

This is the data I am trying to plot, specifically `bar_chart_data['count`] :

```
VEH
0.0     4569.0
1.0    16546.0
2.0    19032.0
3.0     6790.0
4.0     2036.0
5.0      493.0
6.0      207.0
Name: count, dtype: float64
```

Thanks.

Comment: `bar_chart_data.plot.bar(ax=ax3)`

Comment: ^Nothing shows up at all with adding ax=ax3

Comment: You really need to add a full reproducible example.  With the minimal code that reproduces your error.  Without seeing the full code, it is too hard to guess what you're doing wrong. Are you sure the `'count'` column only contains valid, strictly positive values?

Comment: I added the data, and it is all positive values. Does this help enough?

Comment: How is ax3 created? What happens to it along the way? How is the figure created? ..  ?